# Получение результата совпадений по регулярным

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Делаю текстовой анализатор. 
Есть вот такой шаблон для поиска абзацев

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\n\n|(^\\s+)");`

Я просто сплитил текст чрз это шаблон и вроде как работало. Но вот возникла беда. При поиске предложений я использовал уже

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\.|\\!|\\?)");`

и вроде бы работало, только удаляло последний знак препинания(я понимаю из-за чего). Так вот, как бы это получить результат с сохранением всех знаков?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что при разбиении текста методом [Pattern#split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)) в результат не включаются  шаблон, по которому было произведено разбиение. В случае с абзацами у тебя просто пропадали невидимые символы в конце (символы перевода строки). Однако со знаками препинания это уже стало проблемой. Тебе искать само предложение. Примерно так:

```
    String text = "Absa 43 asdqw. Blasrrr sda?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\.|\\!|\\?)");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    while (match.find()) {
        arr.add(match.group());
    }
    Assertions.assertEquals(2, arr.size());
```

Или же вырезать эти предложения через позиции

```
    String text = "Absa 43 asdqw. Blasrrr sda?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\.|\\!|\\?)");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    int lastStart = 0;
    while (match.find()) {
        arr.add(text.substring(lastStart, match.end()));
        lastStart = match.end() + 1;
    }
    Assertions.assertEquals(2, arr.size());
```